# Timer.periodic no funciona correctamente en provider

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy intentando utilizar el método `periodic` de la clase `Timer` dentro de una clase que extiende de `ChangeNotifier` (del paquete [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)) haciendo que cada segundo decremente en uno mi variable `time`.

Esta funciona correctamente si no agrego el método `NotifyListeners` para que redibuje todos los widgets que ocupan la propiedad `time`, de la siguiente forma:

```
class PriceProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  int _time = 60;

  int get time{
    return _time;
  }

  void cronometer(){//método que activa el timer

    Timer _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer){
      print(DateTime.now());//Imprimo la fecha para que vean cada cuanto tiempo se ejecuta el código
      
      _time += -1;//decrementa time

      if(_time == 0){
        _time = 60;
      } 

      // notifyListeners(); 
    });
  } 

}
```

Salida por consola (se ejecuta cada un segundo correctamente):
[image: Salida por consola]

En cambio si descomento el método `NotifyListeners` el código se empieza a ejecutar cada vez más veces por segundo de manera exponencial (por ejemplo, primero se ejecuta una vez, después dos, luego 5, luego 9 y así):
[image: Salida por consola]

Aquí es donde llamo al método `cronometer`:

```
class PriceWithClock extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PriceProvider priceProvider = Provider.of<PriceProvider>(context);
    priceProvider.cronometer();
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
      radius: 100.0,
      lineWidth: 5.0,
      percent: 1-priceProvider.time/60,
      center: Text("00:${priceProvider.time}"),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Creo el `priceProvider` en el `main` de mi proyecto:

```
void main() async{
  runApp(    
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PriceProvider()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: puedes agregar el código como llamas a cronometer()

Comment: @diegoveloper ya lo he agregado

Comment: ok, en que parte añades el ChangeNotifierProvider? es decir en que parte creas el `PriceProvider` ,añade eso también para poner mi respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás creando el `Timer` cada vez que se hace `rebuild`, es decir, cada vez que usas el `notifyListeners` vuelve a entrar al método `build`, por lo tanto llama a `cronometer` entonces vuelve a crear otro `Timer.`

La manera correcta sería crear el `Timer` solo una vez, o también puedes crear una validación para que no vuelva a crear el timer.

Tu clase quedaría así:

```dart
class PriceProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  int _time = 60;
  Timer? _timer;

  int get time{
    return _time;
  }

  void cronometer(){//método que activa el timer
     if(_timer == null){
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer timer){
      print(DateTime.now());//Imprimo la fecha para que vean cada cuanto tiempo se ejecuta el código
      
      _time += -1;//decrementa time

      if(_time == 0){
        _time = 60;
      } 

      notifyListeners(); 
    });
   }
  } 

}
```

Otra forma de solucionarlo, como te decía, solo ejecutar el `cronometer` una vez.

```dart
class PriceWithClock extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PriceProvider priceProvider = Provider.of<PriceProvider>(context);
    // no llamarlo aquí.
    //priceProvider.cronometer();
    return CircularPercentIndicator(
      radius: 100.0,
      lineWidth: 5.0,
      percent: 1-priceProvider.time/60,
      center: Text("00:${priceProvider.time}"),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Llamar al `cronometer` cuando se crea el Provider.

```dart
void main() async{
  runApp(    
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => PriceProvider()..cronometer()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, gracias

Comment: igual lo ideal sería llamar a `cronometer` solo una vez, por eso te decía si puedes añadir como creas el provider para darte más indicaciones

Comment: Ya lo he agregado para que puedas darme más indicaciones

Comment: listo, ya lo actualicé